# My player does not always jump when i press the "jump" button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

In my 2D Unity project my player does not always jump while pressing the "jump" button. He does no jump the second i land on the ground but after a second of "being grounded" he can jump again. What can this problem be?

```
using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class player : MonoBehaviour {

        private static player instance;

        public static player Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<player>();
                }
                return instance;
            }

        }


        private Animator myAnimator;

        [SerializeField]
        public static float movementSpeed;

        private bool facingRight = true;

        [SerializeField]
        private Transform[] groundPoints;

        [SerializeField]
        private float groundRadius;

        [SerializeField]
        private LayerMask whatIsGround;

        [SerializeField]
        private bool airControl;

        [SerializeField]
        private float jumpForce;

        public bool canMove;

        public AudioClip jump001;
        public AudioClip jump002;

        private float direction;
        private bool move;
        private float btnHorizontal;

        public Rigidbody2D MyRigidbody { get; set; }

        public bool Attack { get; set; }

        public bool Jump { get; set; }

        public bool OnGround { get; set; }





        // Use this for initialization
        void Start() {

            facingRight = true;
            MyRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            myAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();




        }
       void Update()
       {

            HandleInput();

        }
        // Update is called once per frame
        void FixedUpdate()
        {

            OnGround = IsGrounded();

            float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

            if (move)
            {
                this.btnHorizontal = Mathf.Lerp(btnHorizontal, direction, Time.deltaTime * 5);
                HandleMovement(btnHorizontal);
                Flip(direction);
            }
            else
            {

                HandleMovement(horizontal);

                Flip(horizontal);
            }

            if (!canMove)
            {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
                myAnimator.SetFloat("speed", 0);
                return;
            }




            HandleLayers();
        }


        private void HandleMovement(float horizontal)
        {
            if (MyRigidbody.velocity.y < 0)
            {
                myAnimator.SetBool("land", true);
            }
            if (!Attack && (OnGround || airControl))
            {
                MyRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * movementSpeed, MyRigidbody.velocity.y);
            }
            if (Jump && MyRigidbody.velocity.y == 0)
            {
                SoundManager.instance.RandomizeSfx(jump001, jump002);
                MyRigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
            }

            myAnimator.SetFloat("speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontal));
        }


        private void HandleInput()
        {
            if (canMove)
            {

                //Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) ||
                if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
                {
                    myAnimator.SetTrigger("jump");

                }
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z) || Input.GetButton("Fight") && OnGround && !Jump)
                {
                    myAnimator.SetTrigger("attack");
                }
            }
        }

        private void Flip(float horizontal)
        {
            if (horizontal > 0 && !facingRight || horizontal < 0 && facingRight && canMove)
            {
                facingRight = !facingRight;

                Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;

                theScale.x *= -1;

                transform.localScale = theScale;
            }

        }


        private bool IsGrounded()
        {
            {

            }
            if (MyRigidbody.velocity.y <= 0)
            {
                foreach (Transform point in groundPoints)
                {
                    Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(point.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);

                    for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void HandleLayers()
        {
            if (!OnGround)
            {
                myAnimator.SetLayerWeight(1, 1);
            }
            else
            {

                myAnimator.SetLayerWeight(1, 0);
            }

        }

        //TouchKnappar

        public void BtnJump()
        {
            if (canMove)
            {


                myAnimator.SetTrigger("jump");
                Jump = true;
            }
        }
        public void BtnAttack()
        {

                myAnimator.SetTrigger("attack");
                Attack = true;

        }
        public void BtnMove(float direction)
        {

                this.direction = direction;
                this.move = true;

        }
        public void BtnStopMove()
        {

                this.direction = 0;
                this.btnHorizontal = 0;
                this.move = false;

        }
        public void BtnStopJump()
        {

                Jump = false;


    }


    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that your character is bouncing a little briefly when he lands, causing the check `MyRigidbody.velocity.y <= 0` to fail? Try using `Debug.Log()` to verify this.

Comment: I'm guessing that the velocity.y is a little off of 0 when on the ground and takes a few seconds to become exactly 0.

And the velocity.y might even be negative for a little bit. So maybe changing (Jump && MyRigidbody.velocity.y == 0) to (Jump && MyRigidbody.velocity.y >= 0) might work.

But, honestly, the whole code should be reworked...

Comment: Okay thank you, i will look in to this. This is my first game and i followed a guy on youtube and have made some changes myself. i do not understand the whole code completly.

Comment: @Serlite, yeah, I was thinking the same thing. Marcus Lönnqvist Try checking with breakpoints also for when it actually hits those certain conditions.

Comment: I can see that the character is bouncing a little bit, which might cause the problem. is there any way to fix that?

Comment: @MarcusLönnqvist A couple ideas come to mind - you could zero out the y-component of the velocity when the player collides with the ground. But first, verify that this is the actual problem by removing the check - if it still doesn't work, then you may need to look elsewhere.

Comment: @Serlite When I added that debug thing to the code it only alerted me when the character had stopped bouncing (we're talking 1/4  second). Which then must mean that the character is not considired grounded until he stops bouncing I think.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this fixed it for me.

This code identifies if the character is grounded in FixedUpdate()

```
Collider2D groundCol = Physics2D.OverlapBox(groundCheck.position, groundBoxRadius, 0f, whatIsGround);
this.grounded = (groundCol != null && !groundCol.isTrigger && this.rigbody2d.velocity.y > -0.01f && this.rigbody2d.velocity.y < 0.01f);
```

Some explanation:

- groundCheck is an empty object at the feet of the character
- In the condition I'm checking if the Overlay box collided with something a and if that something is not a trigger
- Lastly the velocity speed can sometimes be not exactly a 0 so +-0.01f worked for me